# How to create a vector to store predicted values from a list in R?

Tags: r, vector, forecasting, arima

I am developing a forecasting loop for a project and I have been using the function sarima.for form the package ASTSA to execute the forecasts.

Initially, I forecasted just 1 observation on the horizon and I was able to store the forecasted values in a vector that I had created.

However , when I forecast the loop to predict two observation ahead on the horizon , somehow only the first value is stored .

I had created the vector as

```
fc_values <- double(12)
```

But as mentioned , only worked for predictions with 1 n.adead = 1

Then I created a matrix to see if it worked

```
 fc_values=matrix(nrow = 12, ncol=2)
```

But it did not work as well.

Here it is an example of a forecast prediction from this function

```
$pred
      Jan      Feb
2012 20.65135 20.68599

$se
      Jan      Feb
2012 1.734058 2.911538
```

Class of object generated from the forecast function sarima.for is "list".

When I was just forecasting one value It worked with the  example below

```
varii <- sarima.for( xdata = x , n.ahead =1 , 1,0,1) 
fc_values <- varii$pred
```

But now with 2 values , it does not work and the error below appeared :

```
 Not enough forecasts. Check that forecasts and test data match.
 In addition: Warning messages:
 1: In fc_valuesl[i] <- varii$pred :
 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Here is a TS to be as an example

```
     Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov
2008                                                         135.62 213.84 347.80
2009 542.13 462.34 399.07 213.86 122.86  70.32  23.02  23.58  71.64 245.10 310.74
        Dec
2008 467.15
2009 499.75
```

I would appreciate any help to related on how should I structure a vector to store the 2 predicted values that result from the sarima.for command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide an example of how your time series are stored, but here are some options.

Let

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
```

be two sample time series.

Using a vector with unspecified length would look like

```
fc_vec1 <- numeric()
fc_vec1 <- c(fc_vec1, sarima.for(x, 2, 1, 0, 1)$pred)
fc_vec1 <- c(fc_vec1, sarima.for(y, 2, 1, 0, 1)$pred)
fc_vec1
# [1]  0.10913776  0.10869919  0.00957128 -0.05164050
```

that is, we keep adding new elements to the vector. That is, however, not the best option. It seems like you also know the number of predictions. Hence, we may specify the vector length when defining it:

```
fc_vec2 <- numeric(4)
fc_vec2[1:2] <- sarima.for(x, 2, 1, 0, 1)$pred
fc_vec2[3:4] <- sarima.for(y, 2, 1, 0, 1)$pred
fc_vec2
# [1]  0.10913776  0.10869919  0.00957128 -0.05164050
```

Given that your forecasts come from different time series, however, it's not very appealing to concatenate to a single vector. Hence, using matrices is nicer:

```
fc_mat <- matrix(NA, 2, 2)
fc_mat[1, ] <- sarima.for(x, 2, 1, 0, 1)$pred
fc_mat[2, ] <- sarima.for(y, 2, 1, 0, 1)$pred
fc_mat
#            [,1]       [,2]
# [1,] 0.10913776  0.1086992
# [2,] 0.00957128 -0.0516405
```

It's a good idea to store all your time series in a single object. For instance, if we have them in a list `Z`, then we can be much more succinct:

```
Z <- list(x, y)
sapply(Z, function(z) sarima.for(z, 2, 1, 0, 1)$pred)
#           [,1]        [,2]
# [1,] 0.1091378  0.00957128
# [2,] 0.1086992 -0.05164050
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Julius.